# Could not find com.github.everit-org.json-schema:org.everit.json.schema

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I'm trying to add the below dep in my build.gradle and added the below repos but it's still not able to download the dep.

```
repositories {
        maven {
            url 'http://packages.confluent.io/maven/'
        }
        maven {
            url "https://repository.mulesoft.org/nexus/content/repositories/public/"
        }

        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()
    }
```

Below is the error I'm getting:

```
> Could not find com.github.everit-org.json-schema:org.everit.json.schema:.
  Required by:
      project :<my-project-module-name>

Possible solution:
 - Declare repository providing the artifact, see the documentation at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html
```

Answer (score 0):

its my mistake, I've added an extra colon while defining the gradle dependencies..So, it worked after removing it.